# Didehydro cysteine as a modification in unreduced/unalkylated proteomics

Tags: proteomics

I am analysing proteomic data, some of which was digested with the Thermo SMART Digest Kit and some by in-gel digest. I am not a laboratory scientist, and have noted that the samples processed with SMART Digest Kit have very low proportion containing cysteine residues (~0.5% compared to 30% with in-gel digestion). We now have a belated realisation that the SMART Digest Kit does not reduce or alkylate proteins, and that thus disulfide bonds will largely remain.

In an aim to recover as much data as possible, I tried removing the fixed carbamidomethyl mod, however only a few unmodified Cysteines are found. I performed an open search on a small subset of data obtained with high fragment ion resolution, and identified a number of peptides determined to containing cysteine with a -2.0157 Da modification, labelled as "2-amino-3-oxo-butanoic acid" or "didehydro [cysteine]" (shown is -2H on https://www.unimod.org/modifications_view.php?editid1=401). [ed - I appreciate this is not a recognised modification of cysteine!].

If I undertake a fixed search with this as a variable modification I find many more cysteine containing peptides (up to 5%) with a majority with this -2H modification.

However, this modification doesn't seem to be a recognised one for cysteine, and I am no chemist. I wonder if anyone has come across this modification before and can explain it? Ed - I presume it's more likely to represent a different amino acid with a modification which gives a near-identical mass to cysteine -2H.

Incidentally, despite the claims that the SMART Digest kit has immobilised trypsin which should not auto-digest, we have very strong signal from trypsin auto-digestion products!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The link you give doesn't list that modification as being associated with cysteine (or with cystine for that matter) — can you clarify why you think 2-amino-3-oxo-butanoic acid is associated with cysteine? Also, didehydro should be followed by what is being modified — what is it? Please [edit] your post to clarify. Also please note that 'thanks' and 'signatures' are not used on SE sites, so I will edit your post to remove them.

Comment: Never mind about my previous didehydro question I reread your title. However, didehydro cysteine is not the same thing as 2-amino-3-oxo-butanoic acid ...

Comment: Thanks @tyersome - I am also unclear why the -2H modification is described as both didehydro and 2-amino-3-oxo-butanoic acid. Perhaps this is the residue that results when a specific amino acid is "didehydrated."  I don't know enough chemistry to to know if cysteine can be "didehydrated," and I wonder if it's more likely if I'm finding amino acid variants where cysteine has been replaced. No amino acids are constituted by C3H3ONS. The modified monoisotopic mass corresponds to 100.99354 which is closest to the mass of threonine (101.04768), but this is orders of magnitude above a 20ppm error.